# want to use array key in array of object as new property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use array key in array of object as new property javascript
but which method is best for it

I have

```
data =[{
    itemA: 3,
    itemB: 5,
    itemC: 17,
    Marula body scrub: 52,
    Rice bean and soy bean cream: 9,
    Rose cream hand wash: 1
}]
```

I want to change to

```
[
    {name:'itemA',number:3},
    {name:'itemB',number:5},
    {name:'itemC',number:17},
    {name:'Marula body scrub',number:52},
    {name:'Rice bean and soy bean cream',number:9},
    {name:'Rose cream hand wash',number:1},
]
```

any idea to pass it like this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please provide your attempt so far and what isn't working, thanks.

Comment: `Object.entries(data[0]).map(([name, number]) => ({ name, number }))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do:

```
const new_arr = []

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data[0])) {
    new_arr.push({name: key, number: value})
}

console.log(new_arr)
```